# Spring Data CRUDRepository ClasscastException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a gradle multiproject where I have defined multiple entities MyEntity :

- project A contains an entity `a.MyEntity` which maps the table ENTITY. This project contains also a `a.MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long>`.
- project B contains an entity `b.MyEntity` which maps the table ENTITY. This project contains also a `b.MyEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long>`.

  - 1 SpringBoot application which include all the multiprojects.

The entities match the same db table but their scope can be different : mapping all the columns or part of.

At compile time, no error.

At runtime when the assignement is executed in project A : `MyEntity = myEntityRepo.findById(1L);` 
I got a ClassCastException cannot cast b.MyEntity to a.MyEntity

Any idea why ?

Comment: I think it will be better if you put some code et real stack error !

Comment: You may do some think like a.MyEntity = b.myEntityRepo.findById(1L) or vice versa , that's why you got the error that ClassCastException and i think it's normale even if the both a.MyEntity and b.MyEntity contains the same fields.
So make sur that you do : a.MyEntity = a.myEntityRepo.findById(1L); or b.MyEntity = b.myEntityRepo.findById(1L);

Comment: Compile phase is OK. I tried to put the fully qualified name. No changes.

Comment: You got the error during a maven clean install ?

Comment: I'm using gradle, no erro. The CastException happens at runtime.